# SQL Update a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update a column with 1 and 0 based on another column in the same table. Below mentioned query results in error, what is the issue?

**UPDATE A SET [Employee Size Less Than 100]   =    SELECT CASE WHEN [Employee Size] <= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM A

UPDATE A SET [Employee Between 100 and 200]  =  SELECT CASE WHEN ([Employee Size] > 100 AND [Employee Size] <= 200) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM A**

Comment: Which column do you want to update? Your queries update 2 columns: `[Employee Size Less Than 100]` and `[Employee Between 100 and 200]`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a subquery:

```
UPDATE A
    SET [Employee Size Less Than 100] = (CASE WHEN [Employee Size] <= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```